# logging into manager webapp in tomcat 7 shows error

Tags: apache, tomcat, authentication, tomcat7

Installed tomcat7 on my ubunut 12.04 LTS machine, tomcat installed successfully, but when i am trying to login into manager webapp it asks for username and password, on entering it also it doesn't log me in. It gives me 401 unauthorized error page.

here is my tomcat-users.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<tomcat-users>
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->

  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcatadmin" password="123@tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>


<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: I have added the role and users but still i am not able to login to it.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not an error, its a state. You are simply not passing the right credentials. Add a user and some roles ([see here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html)) to the tomcat-users.xml, restart Tomcat and retry.